# Unable to retrieve value from java web service response in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, web-services, actionscript

I am trying to read data from the java web service from flex mxml/action script, seems like the call i.e request/response is successfully but when unable to read the value from the response, please help the MXML code is as below:

```
Unable to print the value from :
var outA:OutputA_type = ccxc.OutputA;
 trace(outA);
var aaa:String = outA.toString();
Alert.show(aaa)
```

it prints as `[Object OutputA)_Type]` but not the required value. however in the flex builder test connection also in the network monitoring I see the proper value/response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:number1="services.number1.*"
               xmlns:testws="services.testws.*"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="850" creationComplete="initApp()">


    <!-- Styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Style source="Styles.css"/>

    <!-- Script ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CalendarLayoutChangeEvent;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

            import services.testws.Testws;

            import valueObjects.OutputA_type;
            import valueObjects.Parameters_type;
            import valueObjects.TestParameters;
            import valueObjects.TestResult_type;

            private function initApp():void  {

                var testWebS:Testws = new Testws();
                var testParam:TestParameters = new TestParameters();
                testParam.ParamA = 2;
                testParam.ParamB = 3;

                var token:AsyncToken = testWebS.test(testParam);

                token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(result, fault));
            }

            private function result(event:ResultEvent) : void {
                trace(event.result);
                var strData:TestResult_type = event.result as  TestResult_type;
                var ccxc:Parameters_type = strData.Parameters;
                var outA:OutputA_type = ccxc.OutputA;
                trace(outA);
                var aaa:String = outA.toString();

                Alert.show(aaa.toString());

            }

            public function fault(event : FaultEvent) : void {
                Alert.show("Failed Condition Fault Exception");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- Declarations ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <!-- UI components ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <s:Label x="10" y="34" 
             width="690" height="40" 
             text="Employee Portal: Vehicle Request Form"
             styleName="titleHeader"/>

    <s:Form x="10" y="70">
        <s:FormItem label="Input a:">
            <s:TextInput id="a"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Input b:">
            <s:TextInput id="b"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem>
            <s:Button id="submitButton" 
                      label="Submit Request" click="submitButton_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>

</s:Application>


SOAP-UI Request:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://tempuri.org/testws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tes:test>
         <tes:parameters>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:ParamA>3</tes:ParamA>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tes:ParamB>1</tes:ParamB>
         </tes:parameters>
      </tes:test>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

SOAP-UI Response:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <m:testResponse xmlns:m="http://tempuri.org/testws">
         <m:testResult>
            <axis2ns794:Parameters xmlns:axis2ns794="http://tempuri.org/testws">
               <axis2ns795:OutputA description="" xmlns:axis2ns795="http://tempuri.org/testws">1</axis2ns795:OutputA>
            </axis2ns794:Parameters>
         </m:testResult>
      </m:testResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
 private function result(event:ResultEvent) : void {
            trace(event.result);
            var strData:TestResult_type = event.result as  TestResult_type;
            var ccxc:Parameters_type = strData.Parameters;
            var outA:OutputA_type = ccxc.OutputA;
            trace(outA);
            var aaa:String = outA.toString();

            Alert.show(aaa.toString());

        }
```

try using Object instead of casting it directly.

```
var retObj:Object = event.result;
var strData:TestResult_type = new TestResult_type();
strData.firstProperty = retObj.firstProperty;
strData.secondProperty = retObj.secondProperty;
```

I think I had an issue with this before where you can't just assign the returned object to a flex object like you can on the java side. If this works then you have to go through each of the event.result objects and set all of the properties of your object through setters.

Comment: +1 Flex itself is unable to convert the returned data into a Typed Object (unless you are using remote objects with mapping). So accept the result as a generic Object and convert that into a typed one by looping through its properties OR through some factory methods.

Comment: How to read data from the strData if I set it as strData:Object = event.result?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment, if you want it to be strData you have to loop through the objects that are returned and create TestResult_type objects by setting their properties to that of the returned object. IF it is only one object you just have to create one variable of TestResult_type and set its properties to each of the properties from the result. That way you can use it as a TestResult_type

Comment: Mike, I tired to follow the above suggestion but once I have OutA how to retrieve the value from it. below is the code snippet which I used:var retObj:Object = event.result;
var aa:TestResult_type = new TestResult_type();
var bb:Parameters_type =new Parameters_type();
var outAA:OutputA_type = new OutputA_type();
aa.Parameters = retObj.Parameters;
bb = retObj.Parameters;
outAA = bb.OutputA;

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Do you still receive the error? If you have OutA it should be of OutputA_type and you should be able to access its properties the same way you would any object of OutputA_type. Could you be a little more specific on what you are looking for?

Comment: Mike, I am able to get to OutputA_type but not sure of exact property which will return the value for the soap response: SOAP Response of OutputA looks like <axis2ns795:OutputA description="" xmlns:axis2ns795="tempuri.org/testws">1</axis2ns795:OutputA>; I am unable to get the value "1" from it and If I use OutputA.toString() obviously returns [Object OutputA_Type] but not the value, I am not sure how to get value from OutputA and not sure which property exactly supports to get data from OutputA_Type?

Comment: You will probably have to write your own .toString() method for your OutputA_type. Are you using an IDE such as Eclipse or FlashBuilder? If so, you can set a breakpoint after you set outA and see if it has the string you are looking for somewhere in its properties. If so you can either make a .toString() function or call that property directly. If not there is something wrong with your logic before there and what you need is not being passed to OutA. I am sorry but I am not very knowledgeable with SOAP :(

Comment: Thanks Mike for the details, I was able to the display outputA response when I generated the form from flex builder itself, this does not resolve the issue completely but its a good point to debug and understand on whats happening during the service call.

Comment: You're welcome! And don't forget to update the question when you find out how to do it so that you can refer to it in the future and others may be able to benefit from your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private function result(event:ResultEvent) : void { 
                trace(event.result); 
                var strData:TestResult_type = event.result as  TestResult_type; 
                var ccxc:Parameters_type = strData.Parameters; 
                var outA:OutputA_type = ccxc.OutputA; 
                trace(outA); 
                var aaa:String = outA.toString(); 

                Alert.show(aaa.toString()); 

}
```

1. What is the response you get while doing `trace(event.result)`
2. Do a trace of this strData, post down what you get.

Comment: trace(event.result) returns: [object TestResult_type]
and trace(outA) returns [object OutputA_type]